# I got Hades' weapons. How do I get back to my Blades of Artemis?

Tags: ps4, god-of-war, god-of-war-3

I just defeated Hades. I sucked up his soul and got his weapons. But I miss my Blades of Artemis.

How can I get back to my old weapons again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens, your weapons are all on the D-Pad. After defeating Hades, you have two weapons. Hades' purple hooks are on the `right` d-pad, and your original blades are `up` on the d-pad.

Fun fact, when you change weapons, it changes the PS4 controller color.

(d-pad is the arrows on the left side of the controller, for you young-ins.)

Comment: Self answered, because it took me an embarrassingly long time to figure this out.

Comment: No problems with answering your own questions, as long as they are of good quality. Also remember to accept the answer as soon as the site lets you to, to help people searching.

Comment: @orc I'll give it 24 hours, as custom on this site, to see if other better answers come in